# Оставить в массиве только числа

Tags: javascript

Есть массив
let arr = [20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3];
Как в нём оставить только числа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С созданием нового массива:

```js
let arr = [20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.filter(item => typeof item === "number")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

С сохранением ссылки:

```js
let arr = [20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3];
let barr = arr;
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (typeof arr[i] !== "number")
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(barr));
```

---

Для тех, кто считает, что можно использовать `.filter(Number)`:

```js
let arr = [20, 33, 0, 1, 2, 3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.filter(item => typeof item === "number")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.filter(Number)));
```

Comment: Первый вариант можно сделать более красиво
[20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3].filter(Number)

Comment: @SpongeAdolf нет, нельзя. Смысл этих двух выражений - разный.

Answer (score 2):

```
[20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3].filter(Number)
```

Comment: Вариант не плохой но если зайдет boolean со значением true в массив?

Answer (score 0):

```
[20, 33, "Человек" ,1, 2, 3].filter(item => +item)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).